# Add list of dictionary to nested dictionary without it being in a list anymore

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flask, jinja2

```
names = ['jan', 'piet', 'joris', 'corneel','jef']
ages = ['one', 'two', 'thee', 'four','five']

namesToDs = [{'name': name} for name in names]
ageToDs = [{'age': age} for age in ages]

concat = [[name, age] for name,age in zip(namesToDs,ageToDs)]


context = {'Team1': {'player1': concat[0] }}
print(context)
```

This will result in the following nested dictionary.

```
{'Team1': {'player1': [{'name': 'jan'}, {'age': 'one'}]}}
```

I want the result to be:

```
{'Team1': {'player1': {'name': 'jan'}, {'age': 'one'}}}
```

So without the [] from the list.

I've tried converting it to a dictonary.
I first had it in a tuple using the list and map function, but that didn't work out.

I'm not very familiar with Python or programming, if I'm shooting in the wrong direction, please let me know.

The reason I want it in this nested dictionary is to be able to easily access the data in flask front end.

Comment: What you want *is not* a valid [standard type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

Comment: Do you instead want: `{'Team1': {'player1': {'name': 'jan', 'age': 'one'}}}`? In that case, replace `[name, age]` with `{**name, **age}`.

Comment: @L3viathan I tested this with some dummy data and I'm indeed able to send what I want to my flask front end! I'm not quite familiar  (yet ;-) )with **name,**age. But this has helped me already, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you expected isn't a possible dictionary. The closest possible would be this:

```
{'Team1': {'player1': {'name': 'jan', 'age': 'one'}}}
```

which is achieved by replacing `[name, age]` with `{**name, **age}`. Full code:

```
names = ['jan', 'piet', 'joris', 'corneel','jef']
ages = ['one', 'two', 'thee', 'four','five']

namesToDs = [{'name': name} for name in names]
ageToDs = [{'age': age} for age in ages]

concat = [{**name, **age} for name, age in zip(namesToDs, ageToDs)]


context = {'Team1': {'player1': concat[0]}}
print(context)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me alot. I was indeed trying to use a 'standard type' as KeepAlive suggested. My problem is solved.

I know this is a beginner mistake, any feedback as to why my question got downvotes?

Comment: Probabaly because people expect you to research about stuff like this and not ask a question. Imho this is what SO is for, so you shouldn't mind asking questions.

Comment: I agree, in hindsight I was googling the wrong questions for hours. Which made me come here. Coming here solved my issue in a few minutes. It's too bad these downvotes will prevent me from asking questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The closest Python valid ([standard type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)) instance is probably

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> {'Team1': {'player1': dict(ChainMap(*concat[0]))}}
{'Team1': {'player1': {'age': 'one', 'name': 'jan'}}}
```

... assuming you have no control on the data generating process, i.e. no control on how `concat` is created.